# Inverse of the difference of matrices

Tags: matrices, inverse, binomial-theorem

Let $A\in R^{n\times n}$ (invertible and symmetric), $B\in R^{k\times k}$ (invertible and symmetric), $C\in R^{n\times k}$, $D\in R^{k\times n}$, $CBD$ is (invertible and symmetric). I am trying to obtain an expression for $(A-CBD)^{-1}$, which does not involve the inverses of $A$ and $CBD$.

As a consequence of the Woodbury identity (or binomial theorem),
$$
(A-CBD)^{-1}=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}[A^{-1} (CBD)]^j \times A^{-1},
$$
but this involves $A^{-1}$, which is unknown. Any suggestions?

Comment: You've told us what you don't want, but..... what *do* you want? One is almost always interested in finding a way of writing $f(x+y)$ in terms of $x,y,f(x),f(y)$, so your question is a little peculiar in that regard.

Comment: Hi dan, I mentioned the binomial theorem, but it could be any other expression that does not involve $A^{-1}$ or $(CBD)^{-1}$, for instance we could multiply the right of both sides by $A$, $(A-CBD)^{-1}A=\sum [A^{-1}(CBD)]^j$, but it still has $A^{-1}$, I want to do some algebra to get rid of $A^{-1}$. This is just a example.

Comment: If, for instance, you let $A - CBD = I - E$, then if all eigenvalues of $E$ have absolute value $<1$ you can write $(A-CBD)^{-1} = \sum_{j=0}^\infty E^j$.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Robert, this strategy seems to lead to the previous binomial theorem, since $(A-CBD)=A(I-A^{-1}CBD)=A(I-E)$, $[A(I-E)]^{-1}=(I-E)^{-1}A^{-1}=$\sum E^j\times A^{-1}$.